# Accessing SAML Login Information in Connected App programmatically

Tags: metadata-api, java, connected-apps, crud

I was looking for a way to programmatically read (and potentially - write) data in SAML Login Information (on ConnectedApp 'manage-side' settings), as displayed below:
[image]

I already tried using Metadata API to pull ConnectedApp metadata, and this is what I found out:

1. ConnectedApp retrieved with Metadata API displays 'create-side' settings, not 'manage-side'.
2. ConnectedAppSamlConfig displays information from Web App Settings in ConnectedApp 'create-side' settings.

Any suggestions on what API I should use?

---

Glossary:

- 'manage-side' – Setup –> Manage Apps –> Connected Apps
- 'create-side' – Setup –> Create –> Apps